# Python integers to strings

Tags: python

Could you say me, how to write a function, which takes as its (one an only) argument a list of numbers and returns a list of string representations of those numbers?

For example `toNum([1, 2, 3, 4])` returns `["1", "2", "3", "4"]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
def to_num(a):
    return map(str, a)

print to_num([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

prints

```
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

Comment: Actually its more "Pythonic" to use list comprehension rather than map(), at least according to Guido. He actually wanted to completely get rid of map() and filter() in favor of list comprehension: http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196

Comment: @Chris: There are two advantages of `map()` though: (1) It's faster and (2) it's less verbose.  I personally find it also more readable in simple cases like this one.  And `map()` is still there even in Python 3, so it seems kind of pointless to claim that just *any* use of this built-in function is not "Pythonic" (a pretty meaningless word anyway).

Comment: This kind of use case is precisely the reason why `map()` and `filter()` stayed, so you can hardly call it unPythonic. However, using a `lambda` expression with `map()` instead of using a list comprehension crosses the line into code that wouldn't make it through any code review I was involved in.

Answer (score 6):

using list comprehension:

```
def stringify(input):
    return [str(num) for num in input]
```

Comment: +1 python-style! (I personally favor list comprehension over `map()`)

Answer (score 2):

Adrien already gave you an elegant answer:

```
def stringify(input):
    return [str(num) for num in input]
```

That works perfectly, but if you intend to only iterate through the representations (and don't need to keep the whole list in memory for any other reason), you should instead do:

```
(str(num) for num in the_list)
```

The parenthesis instead of the brackets indicate a generator expression, just as iterable as a list, but won't fully expand on creation. This may be important if your list is large.

Comment: using python 3, the two are equivalent: list comprehension always returns an iterator...

Comment: @Adrien Plisson: Perhaps you are mistaken; Python 3.2 example: `>>> squares = [x * x for x in range(5)]; type(squares)` produces `<class 'list'>`

Comment: While many things that returned lists in Python 2.x now return iterators (or other custom objects) in Python 3.x, list comprehensions aren't one of them. You may be thinking of other things like `range()`, `dict.keys()`, `dict.values()` and `dict.items()`.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to supply the parameters in the function call

```
def to_num(*numbers):# with the * you can enter as many parameters as you want 
    return [str(x) for x in numbers]
```